# Sign of permutation with first all odd numbers and then even numbers

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles, parity

Let $\sigma \in S_{2n}$ be the permutation defined by
$$\sigma := \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots & n & n+1 & n+2 & \ldots & 2n \\
1 & 3 & 5 & \ldots & 2n-1 & 2 & 4 & \ldots & 2n
\end{pmatrix} $$
What is the sign of $\sigma$?

I wanted to rewrite $\sigma$ as product of cycles but without success.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have certainly tried it for $n=1,2,3,4$. What is the result?

Comment: 1:(1) even; 2:(23);odd; 3 (2354) odd; 4 (235)(478) even; 5 (235986)(47) even; 6 (2,3,5,9,6,11,10,8,4,7) odd.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I tried until $n=8$. It seems to alternate every two times, but I don't see actually how to get a general formula which depend on $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Count the number of swaps to get to the identity.  First move $2$ up to second position, which takes $n-1$ swaps.  Then move $4$ up to fourth position, which takes (how many?) swaps.  Continue up to $2n-2$, which just has to swap once.  Add them all up and see if the sum is even or odd.

Comment: So if I’m not wrong, the correct answer should be $sgn(\sigma)= (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$? (Then I’ll try to prove it by induction)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You sum all the numbers from $1$ to $n-1$ for the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular problem, I would use a different approach to sign. Recall that if a permutation $\sigma$ can be written as a product of $k$ transpositions, then it has sign $(-1)^k$. Another way to say this, is if we write out the permutation as a sequence $$\sigma(1)\,\dots\,\sigma(2n),$$ then we can swap adjacent entries $k$ times to get to $12\dots 2n$. For example, for $1324 \mapsto 1234$, so $1324$ is odd. For the next example, we have $$135246\mapsto 132546 \mapsto 123546 \mapsto 123456,$$ so this one is also odd. If you want to work out a pattern by observation, you will probably have to try up to at least $n=8.$ But if you find a formula for the number of swaps, it should not be too difficult to figure out the parity from that.